# Use calculated value in column in sub-subselect where clausole in Metabase

Tags: mysql, metabase

I hope it is not a duplicity, however I haven't been able to find such an example in given answers. And I expect that skilled sql guy will be able to help me easilly as problem is most likely me.

Please note that I tried really hard to understand similar questions that were mentioned by the system, however none of them pushed me in the face as the one think that I need. Please understand that I am very weak with SQL so maybe it was a correct answer.

Let's have two tables:

azure_tickets:
| ticket_id | system_tags | status |
| -------- | -------------- | -------- |
| 1209     | CZ_released_2023/01/19; IT_released_2023/01/24| For Release |
| 1210     | CZ_released_2023/01/19; HU_released_2023/01/24| Closed |

azure_tickets_history_releases_eav:
| ticket_id | status | days_count |
| -------- | -------------- | -------- |
| 1209    |On Stage            | 12 |
| 1210   | On Stage            | 25 |

Now the first table gets me ticket_id and system_tags (of course more columns there, but for this calculation it is what is needed).

What i need is an average count of days for all tickets with the given system_tag (for single country only, in this case only CZ) for status "On Stage".

We are using metabase, so I was able to creep my way up to the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    `Table A`.`Tags A1` AS                  `Tags A`, 
    `Question 172`.`Azure System Tags` AS   `Tags B`, 
    `Question 172`.`Days On Stage` AS       `Days On Stage`
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT regexp_substr(system_tags, concat({{country}}, '_released_[^;]*')) as "Tags A1"
    FROM            azure_tickets 
    WHERE           azure_tickets.system_tags LIKE concat("%", {{country}}, "_released_%")
    ) 
    `Table A`
    
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            regexp_substr(`Table B`.`system_tags`, concat({{country}}, '_released_[^;]*')) AS `Azure System Tags`,
            SUM(`Table A`.`days_count`) / COUNT(`Table A`.`days_count`) AS                    `Days On Stage`
        FROM (
            SELECT  `azure_tickets_history_releases_eav`.`ticket_id`, 
                    `azure_tickets_history_releases_eav`.`days_count`
            FROM    `azure_tickets_history_releases_eav`
            WHERE   `ticket_id` IN (
                        SELECT  `azure_tickets`.`ticket_id`
                        FROM    `azure_tickets`
                        WHERE   `azure_tickets`.`system_tags` LIKE concat("%", 'CZ_released_2022/12/14', "%") AND 
                                `azure_tickets`.`state` IN ("For release", 'Closed') AND
                                `azure_tickets`.`team_project` NOT IN ('mobile-team','cloud-infrastructure','bart-team','ipf-team','integration-backoffice-team','web-measurements-team','devops-team','ecommerce-sla','qaa-team')) AND
                    `country` = {{country}} AND
                    `status` = "On Stage"
                    )
                    `Table A`
                
        JOIN `azure_tickets` AS `Table B` ON `Table A`.`ticket_id` = `Table B`.`ticket_id`
        ) 
        
        `Question 172` ON `Table A`.`Tags A1` = `Question 172`.`Azure System Tags`
```

Which **almost** gives me what I need. It looks like this:
| Tags A | Tags B | Days On Stage |
| -------- | -------------- | -------- |
| CZ_released_2022/12/14    |CZ_released_2022/12/14            | 25.74 |
| CZ_released_2022/05/12   |            |  |
| CZ_released_2022/07/25   |            |  |
| cz_released_2022/07/28   |            |  |

As you can see on the row 23, there is a where clausole with hardcoded tag (CZ_released_2022/12/14). What I need is to replace this hardcoded tag with the column value Tag A (or B, it doesnt matter), however no matter how I try to update the sql, I get unknown columns in the subselect, for example "Unknown column 'Table A.Tags A1' in 'where clause'".

I am unsure whether the previous queries are needed (ie Question 172, I can per parte it, but I think there is a problem with principe, not the subquery).

I would much appreciate your inputs how to move on with this, I am out of ideas, as I don't use sql and metabase too often.

Answer (score 0):

so I was wrong, I thought this will be easy to solve.
So here is how I had solved it.
I counted all data on backend.
There is a wisdom for me and maybe for you too - if it is too complicated to calculate, simplify it on backend.